# Why does this only insert the last value in the arrays into core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

NSLog says it Successfully adds everything
but when I run this code only the last value in the arrays get added.
Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

```
exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Exercises" inManagedObjectContext: _managedObjectContext];

for (int i = 0; i < [exerciseNames count]; i++)
{
    [exercise setValue:exerciseNames[i] forKey:@"exerciseName"];
    [exercise setValue:exerciseVids[i] forKey:@"exerciseVid"];
    [exercise setValue:machineNames[i] forKey:@"machineName"];
    [exercise setValue:requiresMachine[i] forKey:@"requiresMachine"];
    [exercise setValue:targets[i] forKey:@"target"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if([_managedObjectContext save: &error])
    {
        NSLog([@"Successfully added " stringByAppendingString:exerciseNames[i]]);
    }
}
```

I know this because when I run this it only prints out the last values in the array as opposed to everything

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Exercises" inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Exercise Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"exerciseName"]);
    NSLog(@"Machine Name: %@", [info valueForKey:@"machineName"]);
}
```

Comment: Aren't you just setting the same 5 keys i times?  Those keys don't care whether the values are from an indexed value, they just point to single objects.

Comment: So I would have to create a new NSEntityDescription for each value in the arrays?

Comment: The NSEntityDescription method you're using is a class method that gives you one new Exercises object.  As the answer below says, if you want more than one, yes.

Comment: you are right I had to move this exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Exercises" inManagedObjectContext: _managedObjectContext]; into the for loop

Comment: Yeah, don't think of it as declaring a "description" ... you're calling a class method that returns you a new object in the MOC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to include this line:

```
exercise = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: @"Exercises" inManagedObjectContext: _managedObjectContext];
```

Inside your loop. Since its outside your loop it means you are creating one exercise yet writing to it multiple times. That's why it only has the value of the last element of your array. Move the line into the loop and you should be good :)